# Volumetric lighting is not showing in camera view

Tags: camera, shaders, faces, volumetrics, lighting

I currently have a camera inside a box that has a volume scatter node connected to the material outputs volume. I got my lighting set up (just a lamp) and gave it a view port render not in camera view. the lighting was showing up and it looked great. I then looked at it through the camera and the light didn't show up. So, i did my best to figure out what it was. After multiple observations, i realized this was because when my camera is inside the box, the faces of the box are facing the wrong direction. so where ever i move the camera, if there is any dark shading on the faces, the light wont show up there. So i thought, ill just flip the faces. But, now the volume scatter was being applied outside the box. My goal is to have no problem with this.

**Here is the view port** (this shows the two different shadings of the face-black and grey- in the next picture you will see how the grey shaded area, for some reason, wont let the light be visible to the camera)

[image]

**And here is the view port render** (Notice the relation between the shading and where the light is visible)

[image]

This is the position of the camera...

[image]

This is the position of the cube...

[image]

After going into edit mode and selecting the face of the cube (with volume scatter applied to it) that appeared to have the problem, I realized the camera isn't seeing part of the cube which i'm guessing is causing it to think there should be no volume in that area.

[image]

I decided to move the camera so i could get a better look at things and find if a different position will solve the problem. It did not solve the problem, but it lead me to see something odd happening with the shape. By the way, the gray shape is not an object.

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and change the images you are using. The images you uploaded have a lot of information that is not relevant tot the question (we don't need the curves, timeline or the icons on your desktop...) To make screen grabs in blender use Ctrl F3 and save the image (you can choose to save a window or the whole interface) Please use images that show where the camera is, and how the cube with the volumetrics is set up on the scene. Show also a clear picture of the node tree for  such cube.

Comment: @cegaton I fixed the problems you requested me to fix. Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your camera in order to change your render settings. Change the clipping end to a bigger number.